# Funcion NumberInt en archivo formato json no funciona

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Resulta que tengo un archivo .json donde hay varios objetos. Ese archivo json lo tengo en mi carpeta src de react. La idea es obtener dichos objetos y mostrarlos con react. El problema que tengo es que algunos traen funciones como NumberInt pero eso me da error. Por ejemplo, tengo una propiedad

```
"opcion": NumberInt(2)
```

Eso me genera error a la hora de leerlo con react. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se generó mal tu archivo JSON, si lo que vas a mostrar es un texto puedes encerrar entre comillas `"NumberInt(2)"`, asi te deberia de funcionar.